# Can template parameters of a route template be provided by a bean?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

a route template.

```
 routeTemplate("MyTemplate")
                .templateParameter("incoming")
                .from("file:/tmp/{{incoming}}")
                .to("log:my-log");
```

a route using that template.

```
templatedRoute("MyTemplate")
                .parameter("incoming", "in-test");
```

Is there a way to use a bean, that has a `getIncoming()` method. instead of setting the parameters with the `.parameter()` Method?

Reading the documentation it appears that it should be possible,
but maybe I'm getting it all wrong.
https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-template.html#_binding_beans_to_route_template

I tried to provide a bean.

```
public static class ConfBean
    {
        private String incoming;

        public ConfBean(String incoming)
        {
            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        public String getIncoming()
        {
            return incoming;
        }

        public void setIncoming(String incoming)
        {
            this.incoming = incoming;
        }
    }
```

```
templatedRoute("MyTemplate")
                .bean("confb", () -> new ConfBean("in-bean"));
```

But that returns an error:
`...Failed to resolve endpoint: file:/tmp/{{incoming}} due to: Property with key [incoming] not found in properties from text: file:/tmp/{{incoming}}`